# Knockout total value for each row

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I think I've tried everything on this one, but I cannot figure this out. I'm simply trying to update the total price for each row in a table when the user increases the quantity. So far I've tried

- math in the HTML: `data-bind="text: parseFloat((total * quantity), 10)"`
- using ko.computed() (which "works" but returns the same value for each row's total)
- subscribing to an event
- looping through each observableArray's item with `ko.utils.arrayForEach` and jQuery `$.each()`
- adding a ko.computed property with a `create()` function as part of a mapping option, but I didn't really understand that one.

**[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/YeSZ8/4/)**. If anyone has any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this seemingly simple task I'd appreciate it.

Most of the failed attempts are in the comments on that fiddle. The closest I've come was the ko.computed but I could only get it to return one value - the value for the last row in the table. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to achieve. For simple display purpose a function will do:

```
viewModel.calcTotal = function ( row ) {
    return parseFloat(( row.total() * row.quantity() ), 10);
};
```

There is special variable in `for` loop `$data` that will pass your row data:

```
<td><span data-bind="text: $root.calcTotal($data)"></span></td>
```

Also, your first point with math in HTML will work if you add parentheses. Simple form of binding observables won't work in expressions.

```
data-bind="text: parseFloat(( total() * quantity() ), 10)"
```

Comment: Nice and simple, just what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a working version, I am not too well versed in knockout though so I am not sure if it's "correct".

See the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YeSZ8/7/.

I've created a model for each row called `ItemModel`.

It's defined like this

```
var ItemModel = function (arg) {
    var that = this;

    this.supplier     = arg.supplier;
    this.itemNumber   = arg.itemNumber;
    this.description  = arg.description;
    this.quantity     = ko.observable(parseInt(arg.quantity, 10));
    this.price        = arg.price;
    this.total        = ko.computed(function () {
        return that.price * that.quantity();
    });
};
```

It handles computing the new total value. Instead of using `mapping.fromJSON` which might be more correct I have loaded the json manually and populated the main viewmodel with several rows.

EDIT: I read some about about the mapping plugin and I've come to the conclusion that it should be used with the create method to initiate the ItemModel instances.

EDIT2: Fixed broken filtering, http://jsfiddle.net/YeSZ8/8/

Comment: Thanks Hugo. Any idea how to implement this with the mapping plugin?

Comment: @MarkB I haven't used the mapping plugin myself, but I assume you should be able to create a `create` fallback for each element in the array and make initiate an instance of `ItemModel`.

Comment: Thanks again, but that's where I got stuck on my last bullet point.

Comment: @MarkB I am working on it, almost got it working with the mapping plugin.

Comment: I'm trying too, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @MarkB Got it working, http://jsfiddle.net/YeSZ8/9/. I think you can modify it from here. Good luck, please accept and upvote the answer if you found it to be a good answer to your question.

Comment: Your solution definitely works, and I actually learned more about KO after checking it out, but it was a bit too complex. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution using the mapping plugin:

```
....
var mappingOptions = {
    'cartItemsList': {
        create: function (options) {
            var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {});
            result.total = ko.computed(function () {
                return result.quantity() * parseFloat(result.price());
            });
            return result;
        }
    }
};

var model = {cartItemsList: JSON.parse(jsonData)};
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mappingOptions);
viewModel.filter = ko.observable("");
...
```

The adapted fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YeSZ8/10/

Comment: The filtering isn't working on this one. I'm sure I could get it to work with a few changes, but the chosen answer on this post is a really simple option. Thanks for your help